# Wrap only Two posts in same div - WP While loop

Tags: wordpress

I am setting up new while loop and i want how to manage like below my code

```html
<div class="item">
first post
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="item">
  second post
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  Third post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
fourth post
</div>
```

your help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's not that difficult, you need some incrementation like $i, and some if statement like so:

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
while( something ): 
if ( $i%2 == 0 ) { echo '<div class="col">'; }
?>
<div class="item">
some post
</div>
<?php
if ( $i%2 == 1 ) { echo '</div>'; }
$i++; endwhile; 
?>
```

Above code will take your data (posts) and if its first of two i will prepend it with "col" and if its second of two it will close div.
Im not sure if that is what you wanted, if not let me know :D

EDIT:
When i look at your sample, i can edit above code a little to give you exact result as your sample, so we need to NOT include first post in "col" so we need to make statement that include second post and leaves first:

```
if(i$%4 == 1) { echo '<div class="col">'; }
```

After that we want to close "col" after third post, so:

```
if ( $i%2 == 2 ) { echo '</div>'; }
```

So:

- when `$i = 0` (1st element) We do nothing
- when `$i = 1` (2nd element) We create div with class "col"
- when `$i = 2` (3rd element) We close "col" AFTER we print our post
- when `$i = 3` (4th element) We do nothing

I belive you can see the principal by now :D
Let me know if i can help any more with that

So final code (written in "pure" php just for example ) should look like this:

```
<?php
 if( have_posts ):
  $i = 0; 
   while( have_posts ): the_post;
    if ( $i%2 == 0 ) { echo '<div class="col">'; }
    echo '<div class="item"> some post </div>';
    if ( $i%2 == 1 ) { echo '</div>'; }
  $i++; endwhile; 
?>
```

This is the version i belive will solve your problem:

```
<?php
     if( have_posts ):
      $i = 0; 
       while( have_posts ): the_post;
        if ( $i == 1 ) { echo '<div class="col">'; }
        echo '<div class="item"> some post </div>';
        if ( $i == 2 ) { echo '</div>'; }
      $i++; endwhile; 
    ?>
```

The above code will count iterations of the loop and wrap the second and the third post in "col".

Comment: Thanks for your Reply mate,  i just want to Wrap only 2 posts in while loop not every 2 post

Comment: Hmm sorry for late response, so correct me if im wrong but you want to wrap only two items ? if that is the case i will add some edit to my original post, but keep in mind that this is most basic thing that one can think of :D I don't want to be mean but i belive my 6 year old brother could do that after 3 minutes of googling :D